# Issue in using datatable functions with custom date filter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatable functions in my table but I have made a custom date
filter because initially I am showing records of 6 months but in custom date filter, I have made a query which can fetch records of even last two years.

Now the problem is that when such filter is selected and the records appear, datatable functions don't run on such records as those records were not present initially in the datatable.

I want that on getting records of my custom date filter, I can use datatable functions of sorting, searching and pagination.

Please take a look at the code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" style="width:50%">      
                <div class="input-group input-daterange">
                    <input type="text" id="min" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Start Date">     
                    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>                   
                    <input type="text" id="max" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="End Date">
                </div>          
                <br>
                <center>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fromto()">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFilter()">Remove Filter</button>
                </center>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
  function fromto(){
    var fromDate = document.getElementById('min').value;  
    var toDate = document.getElementById('max').value;  

    if(fromDate=='' || toDate==''){
        alert("Please select a valid date");
    }
    else{
        $.post("../db/get_inspections.php",{fromDate:fromDate,toDate:toDate}, function(x){
            var table = document.getElementById("example1");
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var j=rowCount-1;j>0;j--){
                table.deleteRow(j);
            }
            var data = JSON.parse(x);
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                //alert(data[i].hseresult);
                $('#example1').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_checkbox" value="'+data[i].inspection_id+'"></td><td>'+data[i].station+'</td><td>'+data[i].outlet_code+'</td><td>'+data[i].division+'</td><td>'+data[i].salesarea+'</td><td>'+data[i].inspectedby+'</td><td>'+data[i].date+'</td><td>'+data[i].time+'</td><td><button class="'+data[i].gainlossresult+'" onclick="inspection(\''+data[i].inspection_id+'\',\''+data[i].station+'\',\''+data[i].outlet_code+'\',\''+data[i].division+'\',\''+data[i].salesarea+'\',\''+data[i].date+'\',\''+data[i].time+'\',\''+data[i].station_type+'\',\''+data[i].outlet_category+'\')" type="button">Inspection</button>&nbsp;<button class="'+data[i].hseresult+'" onclick="hse(\''+data[i].inspection_id+'\',\''+data[i].station+'\',\''+data[i].outlet_code+'\',\''+data[i].division+'\',\''+data[i].salesarea+'\',\''+data[i].date+'\',\''+data[i].time+'\')" type="button">HSE</button>&nbsp;<button class="'+data[i].fcresult+'" onclick="forecourt(\''+data[i].inspection_id+'\',\''+data[i].station+'\',\''+data[i].outlet_code+'\',\''+data[i].division+'\',\''+data[i].salesarea+'\',\''+data[i].date+'\',\''+data[i].time+'\')" type="button">FORECOURT</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="remove(\''+data[i].inspection_id+'\')" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td>'+'</tr>');
            }


        });
    }
  }
```

Please guide me how to resolve this issue. Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks